# Application of Banach Steinhaus theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and let $A:X\rightarrow Y,B:Y^*\rightarrow X^*$ be linear maps.

Show that if for all $x\in X,y\in Y^*,y^*(Ax)=By^*(x)$, then both $A$ and $B$ are continuous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noting that for a fixed $x$ and $\|y^*\| \le 1$, the map $y^* \mapsto y^*(Ax)$ is bounded uniformly by $\|Ax\|$.

Then Banach Steinhaus gives $\sup_{\|x\| \le 1, \|y^* \| \le 1} |y^*(Ax)| < \infty$.

We have $\|B\| = \sup_{\|y^*\| \le 1} \|B y^*\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1, \|y^*\| \le 1} |B y^*(x)| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1, \|y^*\| \le 1} |y^*(Ax)| $,
hence we see that $B$ is bounded.

The other direction follows directly from this bound.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain me why $\sup_{||y^*||\leq 1}||By^*||=\sup_{||x||\leq 1,||y^*||\leq 1}|By^*(x)|$ is true? I am understanding it correctly then we are dealing here with 2 operator norms.

Comment: If $x^* \in X^*$ then we have $\|x^*\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |x^*(x)|$. Here $B y^* \in X^*$.

Comment: Hello. Sorry that I have to ask again. I hope you will answer my remaining questions: 1) $y^*(Ax)$ is uniformly bounded by $||Ax||$. But why $||Ax||<\infty$? How we know this? If we want to apply Banach Steinhaus, then we need finiteness, correct? 2) I was not able to see that $||A||<|infty$ aswell can you explain it to me?

Comment: $Ax$ is just an element of $Y$ so it has finite norm. The operator $A$ is defined everywhere, so $Ax \in Y$ for all $x$. I showed that $B$ is bounded above, not $A$. However, since $B$ is bounded, the above also shows that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Note that $\|x\| = \sup_{\|x^*\| \le 1} |x^*(x)|$ by Hahn Banach. It might help to carefully distinguish the norms on $X,Y$, $X^*,Y^*$ and the operator norms.

Comment: I can't see why Banach Steinhaus gives that $\sup_{||x||\leq1,||y^*||\leq1}|y^*(Ax)|<\infty$. The maps $y^*\mapsto y^*(Ax)$ are uniformly bounded, hence Banach Steinhaus yields that $\sup_{||y^*||\leq1}||y^*||$ is bounded? But this is trivial.

Comment: Each $x$ defines a linear operator $y* \mapsto y^*(Ax)$. Banach Steinhaus says that if for each $x$ you have $\sup_{ \|y^* \| \le 1} |y^*(Ax)| < \infty$, then $\sup_{\|x\| \le 1, \|y^* \| \le 1} |y^*(Ax)| < \infty$. That is the 'big deal' about Banach Steinhaus; pointwise bounded implies bounded.